# How to launch localhost automatically in angular.. with out manually typing localhost:4200?

Tags: angular

If i compile and run  an angular 2 (or above) application i need to manually go ,to the browser and type localhost path for the output.I need to open the browser automatically whenever i use ng serve command.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you share some code illustrating your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ng serve --open

or

> ng serve -o

This will automatically opens your default browser to http://localhost:4200/.

Answer (score 1):

```
ng s -o
 or
ng serve -o
```

where ng is angular ,s is serve and o is open in the default port(i.e 4200)

serve the angular in the default port

Answer (score 1):

if you are using angular-cli change your `package.json` as below than type `npm start`

```
...
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --open",
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the `package.json`

```
..
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --open",
```

Or write the command to your terminal
`ng serve -o`

This will automatically open your default browser.

Answer (score 1):

you can also try with a more flexible config

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "ng serve && open http://localhost:4200"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to write a script to do this. Instructions can be found here
[How to open browser to localhost through npm scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40713752/how-to-open-browser-to-localhost-through-npm-scripts)