# Problem with import from node_modules in javascript

Tags: javascript, npm, import, node-modules

I've been struggling with this problem for days. The problem is that import works badly and I don't know why. Here are some examples:

I have an index.html, completely empty, I only have the script. Like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="module" src="/src/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Inside src folder I have index.js and app.js. In app.js the code is:

```
const helloWorld = () => {
  console.log('Hello world');
};

export default helloWorld;
```

In index.js the code is:

```
import helloWorld from 'app.js';
helloWorld()
```

I use the VSC Live Server extension to mount the server, the Chrome console said:

*Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "app.js". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".*

I said: "Ok", and I try this in index.js:

```
import helloWorld from './app';
helloWorld()
```

Chrome console said:

*GET http://127.0.0.1:5500/src/app net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)*

This problem also happens to me with all npm packages that are in node_modules. Examples:

```
import bootstrap from 'bootstrap';
import axios from 'axios';
```

Chrome console:

*Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "bootstrap". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".*

*Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "axios". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".*

VSC recognizes the axios and the bootstrap routes but when trying in the browser something breaks. Examples:

[image: axios route]

I also tried using another local server, but it didn't work either. I tried the one explained in this link:

[How to open browser to localhost through npm scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40713752/how-to-open-browser-to-localhost-through-npm-scripts)

Something else to add is that it says the error is on line 1 of the index.html:

[image: chrome console error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. regarding the import of `app.js` inside `index.js` - you just need to write:

`import helloWorld from './app.js';`

and it's working!

2. As for node modules, this is more complicated. Usually on project set-up (take an automatic one such as create-react-app) there's a JS BUNDLER that is installed, like Webpack, rollup.JS Parcel etc. . Those, by the way, help you with js files references and imports... But once you create an empty project and than use `npm install` without a bundler or package.json and more configuration - it will be harder to import.

read [this article](https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/how-to-use-npm-and-import-export-modules-in-javascript-31a7f66a2064) about how to install modules on JS project

Comment: Thank you the 1. works. The 2. is as you say and is explained in the article. With create-react-app or similar is already configured. But the article also says that with webpack you can use it. And I tried with webpack and it also gave me errors, I will continue trying with webpack.

Comment: I'm giving an update on the situation. Webpack is the solution to 2. I already did what I wanted, without Webpack you can't.